# Passing HashMap to AsyncTask and convert it to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-asynctask, hashmap

I'm sending a request to a 3rd party web server that gives a JSON response. The response contains information on users. Each user has a "refid" and some other elements about the user. I currently iterate over the results and store each user into a Hashmap and than add the map to (ArrayList Hashmap String,String) I than populate a listview with this data. Now what I want to do, is when a users press a button on the listview it pulls all the refids from the Arraylist and sends to my server via AsyncTask to look for matches against the refids.

My question is how should I send the refids to a asyntask when the number of refids can vary? Could I get the values and keys and create a JSONObject which I can send to my server? For example {refid=123,refid=345,refid=678}. What would be the params of the asynctask?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like the following :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Hashmap<String , String> map  = yourArrayList.get(position); 

    MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(map); 
task.execute()
    }
});
```

Here i am getting the hashmap from your ArrayList based on the position clicked ;

and i pass the hashMap to the AsyncTask with the constructer , then i execute the Asynctask like the following :

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void> {

    private Hashmap<String , String> map ; 


    public MyAsyncTask (HashMap<String,String> m ){
        this.map = m ; 
    } 

    … 

}
```

and in your asynctask you can convert the HashMap to JSONObject  :

[public JSONObject(java.util.Map map)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.util.Map%29)

the JSONObject constructer takes a Map as arguments and constructs a JSONObject from the Map like the following :

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(yourmap);
```

And please give me feedback .

Hope that helps .

Comment: thanks for the fast response. Can I take that map and use a JSONParser to convert it to a JSONobject?

Comment: yes sure , you can convert this map to a JSONObject .

Comment: I don't know how to convert the map to a object. I'm use to using a JSONParser (URL, List<NameValuePair> params) I would add the string values as params, but this is different for me. Can you help me further?

Comment: check my updated answer the JSONObject constructer takes a HashMap and converts it to JSONObject